# Is it safe to declare non-virtual destructor in the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor, virtual-functions

In the program:

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A(){ }
};

struct B : A
{
    ~B(){ }
};
int main(){ }
```

The Standard `N4296::12.4/9`:

> If a class has a base class with a virtual destructor, its destructor
>   (whether user- or implicitly-declared) is virtual.

So, the compiler will redeclare the destructor in the struct `B` as a virtual on its own, right? Why are we permitted to declare such a destructor then? It may be a little confusing to another developer.

Comment: I guess its like, if you omit the `virtual` keyword, it inherits its virtuality from its base class.

Comment: All functions work the same way. Yes it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function overriding a virtual member function is always virtual, no matter you declare `virtual` or not. Thus `B::~B()` is always virtual since `A::~A()` is virtual.

Comment: Some proof-reference from the standarn?

Comment: @DmitryBundin: You already quoted the relevant sentence from the standard in your question. It's unclear what else you might be looking for.

Comment: @GregHewgill I only quoted the section about destrctuors, but timrau in turn was talking about all virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your understanding is right.

> Why are we permitted to declare such a destructor then?

I agree with you that it's a little confused, but you can remove the virtuallity of the function of all the base and derived classes by just removing the `virtual` from the base class.

Comment: "you can remove the virtuallity of the function of all the base and derived classes by just removing the virtual from the base class." - in general,  justifying decreasing readability via "less amount to type" is a Bad Thing, as "code is read much more times than it is written"